# How to fill gaps in date column?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe df with daily sales numbers per product "id" and product "qual"ity like:

```
date       | id | qual | col1 | col2 | col3
2020-10-01 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-02 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-05 | a  | B    | 13   | 8    | 7
2020-10-02 | a  | C    | 3    | 6    | 9
2020-10-05 | a  | C    | 26   | 16   | 14
2020-10-02 | b  | B    | 100  | 200  | 300
2020-10-04 | b  | B    | 49   | 19   | 9
```

Product = column "id"

For days with 0 sales I don't have entries, so they are missing. But I would like to add those missing days for each produt "id".

The end date for each product should be a date I can set via a variable, like

```
end_date = "2020-10-10"
```

or the latest date in the whole dataframe (for any product "id") like

```
end_date = "2020-10-05"
```

The result should look like (for variable end_date = "2020-10-10"):

```
date       | id | qual | col1 | col2 | col3
2020-10-01 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-02 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-03 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-05 | a  | B    | 13   | 8    | 7
2020-10-06 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-07 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-08 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-09 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-10 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-01 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-02 | a  | C    | 3    | 6    | 9
2020-10-03 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-05 | a  | C    | 26   | 16   | 14
2020-10-06 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-07 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-08 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-09 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-10 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-01 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-02 | b  | B    | 100  | 200  | 300
2020-10-03 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | b  | B    | 49   | 19   | 9
2020-10-05 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-06 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-07 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-08 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-09 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-10 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
```

Or like this (for latest date in date column = "2020-10-05")

```
date       | id | qual | col1 | col2 | col3
2020-10-01 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-02 | a  | B    | 1    | 2    | 3
2020-10-03 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | a  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-05 | a  | B    | 13   | 8    | 7
2020-10-01 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-02 | a  | C    | 3    | 6    | 9
2020-10-03 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | a  | C    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-05 | a  | C    | 26   | 16   | 14
2020-10-01 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-02 | b  | B    | 100  | 200  | 300
2020-10-03 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
2020-10-04 | b  | B    | 49   | 19   | 9
2020-10-05 | b  | B    | 0    | 0    | 0
```

How can I do this for each variant in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) in lambda function per groups like:

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

end_date = "2020-10-10"
df = (df.set_index('date')
        .groupby(['id','qual'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), end_date), fill_value=0))
        .drop(['id','qual'], axis=1)
        .rename_axis(['id','qual','date'])
        .reset_index())
```

---

If there is error you need preprocessing data, add code before `groupby + apply` solution:

> "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

it means there are duplicates per `id` with `date`s.

Possible solutions is first remove duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['date','qual','id'])
```

Or aggregate, e.g. by sum:

```
df = df.groupby(['date','qual','id']).sum()
```

Comment: It's "fill_value". But with duplicate entries in date (which are there by design) I get "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"?

Comment: Same error with the lambda version: "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: @Vega - It means there are duplicated dates per `id`, it is expected?

Comment: No, but I forgot that I have product quality in a column (edited my example), so a product can have one of 2 qualities and only date+product id+quality is unique. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Vega - `"TypeError: 'fill_value=0' is not present in this Categorical's categories"` is possible remove, need some time.

Comment: @Vega - What is `print (df.select_dtypes('category').columns.tolist())` ? It is `id` and `qual` ? Or many another columns?

Comment: It's "id", "qual" and many other columns (but not all). 24 of 75 columns are of type "category". Those other columns can all be filled with NaN.

Comment: I had indeed 2 duplicate rows due to an unknown overlap in 2 unofficial holidays. After removing those and removing "fill_value" (to make it default to NA) it works. Thanks a lot!